# When I define a value in my Android script, it gives me an Error

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Android and Kotlin and wanted to make an App where it ramdomly gives you Teams with random Teammates. I tried storing the names of the players with SharedPreferences and had to define some Values(I don't understand what Values are) but when i define them, it crashes the app.
I know to proplem has to do with the values because if I delete them the App runs fine.

The enterName script

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView

class enterName : AppCompatActivity() {

    var namesButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
    var namesText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.namesText)
    var outputText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.outputText)


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_name)

        namesButton.setOnClickListener {
            saveData()
        }
    }

    private fun saveData() {
        val insertedText = namesText.text.toString()
        outputText.text = insertedText

        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("namesPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.apply {
            putString("namesPref", insertedText)
        }.apply()

    }
}
```

The Activity script

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".enterName">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/namesText"
        android:layout_width="379dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Player Names"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="286dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/separateNames"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#5A5A5A"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/namesText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="NEXT"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outputText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="hi"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The Error/Log

```
2022-04-04 19:55:37.994 6997-6997/? I/.teamrandomize: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2022-04-04 19:55:38.000 6997-6997/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer E/.teamrandomize: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2022-04-04 19:55:37.994 6997-6997/? I/.teamrandomize: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2022-04-04 19:55:38.000 6997-6997/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer E/.teamrandomize: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2022-04-04 19:55:37.994 6997-6997/? I/.teamrandomize: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2022-04-04 19:55:38.000 6997-6997/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer E/.teamrandomize: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2022-04-04 19:55:38.122 6997-7031/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
2022-04-04 19:55:38.122 6997-7031/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
2022-04-04 19:55:38.118 6997-6997/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:42): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=6596 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c144,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0 app=at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer
2022-04-04 19:55:38.127 6997-7031/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2022-04-04 19:55:38.128 6997-7031/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2022-04-04 19:55:38.129 6997-7031/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2022-04-04 19:55:38.153 6997-6997/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer W/.teamrandomize: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-04-04 19:55:38.153 6997-6997/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer W/.teamrandomize: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-04-04 19:55:38.191 6997-7029/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7b23c96400, tid 7029
2022-04-04 19:55:38.193 6997-7029/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2022-04-04 19:55:38.194 6997-7029/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2022-04-04 19:55:38.195 6997-7029/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x7b23c965e0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2022-04-04 19:55:38.195 6997-7029/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7b23c965e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7b23c18f00)
2022-04-04 19:55:38.203 6997-7029/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2022-04-04 19:55:38.205 6997-7029/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2022-04-04 19:55:38.206 6997-7029/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7b23c96720, tid 7029
2022-04-04 19:55:38.206 6997-7029/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2022-04-04 19:55:38.206 6997-7029/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x1000
2022-04-04 19:55:38.207 6997-7029/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x1fef08000 size 0x8000
2022-04-04 19:55:38.210 6997-7029/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7b23c965e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7b23c18f00)
2022-04-04 19:55:39.253 6997-6997/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 1472 bytes, containing 1 windows, 8 views
2022-04-04 19:55:40.804 6997-6997/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@2616b45
2022-04-04 19:55:40.808 6997-6997/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2022-04-04 19:55:40.809 6997-6997/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer, PID: 6997
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer.enterName}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:163)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:174)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:738)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:848)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:815)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:640)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:259)
        at at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer.enterName.<init>(enterName.kt:12)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1243)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
2022-04-04 19:55:40.819 6997-6997/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6997 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Go here https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what "Values" you're talking about, but your app is crashing because of this error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer/at.thebuckey_.teamrandomizer.enterName}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference`

which is saying you're trying to call `getApplicationInfo()` on a `Context` that's actually null. That's happening because of this:

```
class enterName : AppCompatActivity() {

    var namesButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
    var namesText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.namesText)
    var outputText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.outputText)
```

Calling `findViewById` in an `Activity` requires its `View` hierarchy (so you can find the View you're searching for inside it), and long story short, that call is what's trying to use the Activity's `Context`. And it doesn't have one at construction time, so the context is **null**.

You need to do all your view-finding in `onCreate` or later, at which point you *do* have a `Context` (for view lookups, specifically after the view has been created, e.g. with `setContentView`). Do this instead:

```
class enterName : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var namesButton: Button
    lateinit var namesText: TextView
    lateinit var outputText: TextView


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_name)

        namesButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
        namesText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.namesText)
        outputText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.outputText)

        namesButton.setOnClickListener {
            saveData()
        }
    }
```

`lateinit` lets you declare those top-level variables, but **init** them **late**r (i.e. when you have the `Context` you need)

---

With the "Values" thing, when you store data in shared prefs you need a key/value pair - the key is the identifier you use to store a piece of data, the value is the data itself, that's all. You're doing it here:

```
editor.apply {
    putString("namesPref", insertedText)
}.apply()
```

That's storing `insertedText` (the value) using the lookup key `"namesPref"`. So you can retrieve that value later with `getString("namesPref")`. Since that's also the name of your `SharedPreferences` store I'm guessing you wanted to use a different name for your lookup, but that's the basics of it